# Remapping object properties

Tags: javascript, object

Consider this definition object:

```
var map = {
  'Username':
  {
    'user-name': 'userName',
    'first-name': 'fName',
    'last-name': 'lName',
    'active': 'isActive'
  }
}
```

How can I remap an object, for instance, this:

```
data: 
{
   'user-name': SamN,
   'first-name': Sam,
   'last-name': Norbert,
   'active': 1
}
```

to get an output like this:

```
data:
{
   'userName': SamN,
   'fName': Sam,
   'lName': Norbert,
   'isActive': 1
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply iterate over the properties:

```
for(var prop in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop in map.Username) {
        data[map.Username[prop]] = data[prop];
        delete data[prop];
    }
}
```

This changes the object in-place. If you want to create a new object, just set the properties on a new empty object.

You can also iterate over the properties of `map.Username` instead.

Comment: If I put this in a function, does JS support passing by reference? Or do I create a temporary object?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Objects are always passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
const map = {
  'Username':
  {
    'user-name': 'userName',
    'first-name': 'fName',
    'last-name': 'lName',
    'active': 'isActive'
  }
}
const newObj = {};
const oldObj = { 'user-name': 'SamN', 'first-name': 'Sam', 'last-name': 'Norbert', 'active': 1 };

// Solution
Object.keys(oldObj).map((v, k) => {
    newObj[map.Username[v]] = v
})

console.log(newObj) // {userName: "user-name", fName: "first-name", lName: "last-name", isActive: "active"}
```